# Accessing a string in aspx from the code behind. | title=<%=(tooltipAGE)%> vs. title='<%=(tooltipAGE)%>'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string defined in the code behind like this :

```
protected string tooltipAGE = "Product Exceeds Age Spec Limit - age exceeds max allowed limit.";
```

When I try to use this variable in my aspx page like this :

```
<a href="AGE_Home.aspx" title=<%=(tooltipAGE)%>>AGE</a>
```

It only shows the first word of the string "product", everything after that gets cut off...

But if I use ,

```
<a href="AGE_Home.aspx" title='<%=(tooltipAGE)%>'>AGE</a>
```

It shows the full text as I expect.

I am trying to understand why it only shows the first word when I try it the first way.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Read the generated source.

Comment: @SLaks Ok.. I see it now.  Its not inside the quotes.. Thanks for the help :) I am still a newbie...